# resize stack of images pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I have a tensor with shape torch.Size([5, 240, 240, 155]) which is a 5 different channels with 155 images of 240x240. I want to make those images 128x128 so the final shape would look like this.

torch.Size([5, 128, 128, 155]).
transforms.Resize only affects the last two dimensions, and reshaping in messes up the images, as it does not understand that there are 155 different images and mixes them up. Is there a better way to do this than a for loop that iterates over every image, reshapes it and then concatenate them?

Comment: there is an issue about this on GitHub:  https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/157

Answer (score 0):

Try to transpose the tensor (or just load the images differently) to obtain

```
torch.Size([240, 5, 240, 155])
```

Then reshape to

```
torch.Size([240*5, 240, 155])
```

Then use `Resize`.